# AsyncTask how to use progressbar

Tags: android

I want to implement a progress bar while a function is getting executed.This will help me to notify user that something is going on for updation.
But I am not able to see any progressbar instead I see Logcat message as progressBar dimensions.

```
class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() 
                    {
                        ProgressDialog progress=new ProgressDialog(App_list_Activity.this);
                        progress.setTitle("Please Wait while sync is in progress!!");
                        progress.setMessage("Database is getting updated...");
                        progress.setCancelable(true);
                        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                        progress.show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
                    {
                      updateDatabase();
                    return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
                    {
                        ProgressDialog progress=new ProgressDialog(App_list_Activity.this);;
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                new Async().execute();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: No need to create progress in *onPost*. remove it..just use `progress.dismiss();` in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

Declare ProgressDialog at class level :

```
class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
ProgressDialog progress;
```

Initialize in onPreExecute() :

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
progress=new ProgressDialog(App_list_Activity.this);
```

Dismiss in onPostExecute() :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
progress.dismiss();
```

In your code you again Initialize ProgressDialog in onPostExecute() for dismiss onPreExecute  ProgressDialog so it will create new ProgressDialog instance and dismiss it but still onPreExecute() ProgressDialog is not dismiss.

**Example :**

```
class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        progress=new ProgressDialog(App_list_Activity.this);
        progress.setTitle("Please Wait while sync is in progress!!");
        progress.setMessage("Database is getting updated...");
        progress.setCancelable(true);
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        updateDatabase();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
new Async().execute();
```

Comment: Instead of put only code try to explain what his doing wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: Just additional information I am using this async Task class inside my mainActivity

Comment: Thanks Naveen and Haresh but I see only function is getting executed the progress bar is not shown

Comment: Hey I think progressbar is showing up but may be due to very less time gap between onpreexecute and postexecute it gets dismissed or so....Any option to have it longer.Length_long

Answer (score 0):

As the Android documentation states :

onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private ProgressDialog progress;

class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() 
                    { progress= new ProgressDialog(SingleContactActivity.this);

                        progress.setTitle("Please Wait while sync is in progress!!");
                        progress.setMessage("Database is getting updated...");
                        progress.setCancelable(true);
                        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                        progress.show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
                    {
                      updateDatabase();
                    return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
                    {
                if (progress.isShowing())
                progress.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                new Async().execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating one instance in `onPreExecute` and another in `onPostExecute`. You should keep the reference and dismiss that one.

On top of that I suggest keeping the member `progress` final, otherwise Android might scream about leak.

Furthermore, dismiss dialog should be in `onCancelled` as well.

```
class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final ProgressDialog progress;

    public Async(Context c) {
        super();
        this.progress = new ProgressDialog(c);
        progress.setTitle("Please Wait while sync is in progress!!");
        progress.setMessage("Database is getting updated...");
        progress.setCancelable(true);
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        updateDatabase();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (progress.isShowing()) {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        if (progress.isShowing()) {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}

new Async().execute();
```

HTH.

Comment: what should be the Context when the Async Task is separated from the mainactivity class.

Comment: Pass in reference to yours Activity or ApplicationContext; I modified the code to take Context as constructor parameter.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fundamentals

Comment: Still I am not able to see the progress bar as I think progress.show and progress.dismiss time gap is very less(ie may be the function takes mircro secs to get executed or so) I tried with if(progress.isShowing()){progress.show()} and the progressbar was visible.Please give some workaround

Comment: Now this worked for me.I added Thread.sleep(10000); in try catch in  the doInBackground function